# Request-scoped property in controllers

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, controller

I'm relative new to Spring so there is a thing not very obvious for me. Namely, the fact that controllers are singletons. I agree that this is a good approach but this doesn't let me implement a thing that I used to implement with other frameworks.

I build a web application which throughout uses AJAX requests. I have controllers hierarchy with `BaseController` as parent and all other controllers extend it.

Controller actions which should return response to the client are annotated with the `@ResponseBody` annotation and return serialized JSON string to the client.

Method `createJSONResponse()` which performs this serialization is implemented in the `BaseController` and the main idea here is that each of the child controllers' actions populates a map `Map<String, Object> responseMap` with the required for client data and then this map is accessed in the `BaseController` and serialized.

I don't want to create new instance of `responseMap` in every action and I don't want to pass it every time as a parameter for `createJSONResponse()`.

I achieved this with other framework by declaring `responseMap` in `BaseController` as `protected` property.

I can't do this with Spring since all controllers are singletons and I will not have new instance of `responseMap` with every request.

I'm not sure making `BaseController` request scoped is a good idea.

I created a helper class as request scoped bean and declared responseMap in this helper. Then I injected this bean as `@Autowired` in `BaseController`. I also moved out `createJSONResponse()` method in this helper. Then from controllers I populate this map as `helper.responseMap.add(<somedata>)` and call `helper.createResponseMap()`.

In this case `responseMap` becomes empty in `createResponseMap()`, it does not contain data populated in controller action. It somehow goes out that `responseMAp` is not thread-safe and it is moving from thread to thread with each async request.

Are there any ways to achieve functionality I need?

---

**SOLVED BY A WORKAROUND:**
Solved the problem by instantiating responseMap before every request and adding to the HttpServletRequest object in request interceptor. Then createJSONResponse() method and responseMap population methods refer to the getRequestMap() method which gets responseMap from the HttpServletRequest.

P.S. Still will be glad to know the better solution.

Comment: "I don't want to create new instance of responseMap in every action and I don't want to pass it every time as a parameter for createJSONResponse()"   --- why not?  This is the cleanest, easiest to read design.

Comment: Yes. This is clean but not the best solution in my opinion. I would rather like DRY approach with not having the same line of code repeating throughout the controllers' actions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this right (thread-safe) you will be forced at some point to have one instance of that map for each request (if you really want to inject that in a singleton, you can use a scoped proxy -- but you'll end up with the exact same result, only more complicated.

My advice would be to make use of a template method and get rid of that protected property; just define an abstract method which will return the populated map in each subclass.

If you just want to get rid of writing `Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>()` in all your concrete controllers, you can do that in the base controller (for every request) and then use the abstract method only to populate that map (but the instance will be a fresh one every time).

Here's how it would look in the base controller:

```
public String handleRequest() {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    populateModel(model);
    model.put("success", true);  // as a response to your comment
    return serializeModel(model);
}

protected abstract void populateModel(Map<String, Object> model);
```

P.S.
As a side note (although this may be the actual answer to your question), Spring is able to serialize your response in several formats if you just return them as type-safe objects. Just include the jackson mapper in your classpath (to enable JSON format), add some JAXB annotation on your model class and return your model as a `MyBean` instance. Spring will marshal that as XML / JSON given that you provide the proper `Accept:` header or define the proper `produces` in your request mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not sure it's the solution because I need the map shared between base and children controllers within a request. I need to populate the map in a child controller action, then add to this map some data common for all responses (ex, responseMap.add("success", true) ) in BaseController method.
With the approach you've proposed I will not be able to do this, as far as I understand.
What to JSON response, I already use FlexJSON to properly serialize Hibernate entities.

Comment: There's no problem to add whatever you want to that map after the `populateModel` call. You have full control in the base controller to do whatever you want with it (even replace it with another one if you don't like what the subclass did). -- see my edit to the code

Comment: Yes, I see, but in this case I will have to implement populateModel in child controllers and call it in every action. I will also have to pass new instance of map in every action to the populateModel method what is an even more overhead than simply pass the newly created map directly in handleRequest(). Or do I miss something?

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same workflow. What I understood is that you have a base controller that will catch all the requests (so any request coming in will be processed by this `handleRequest`).   This looks very much like the vintage spring `AbstractController` design. Is this assumption wrong ?

Comment: No, that's not quite right. Base controller doesn't catch all the requests. Every controller has his own actions.

Comment: Found a kind of solution. See the first post. Thanks.